# Coolant level stays the same for weeks, then suddenly drops

Tags: coolant-leak

2009 ranger sport 4x4 - 4.0l v6.

I noticed the coolant was low, and not knowing what had previously been in there, I flushed the coolant and filled with an approved coolant for the vehicle.

I ran the heater, A/C, etc for a while to make sure the entire system was filled with new coolant, and then topped the overflow bottle to the fill line.

This held for about 3 weeks, then suddenly the overflow bottle was empty. Filling it resulted in the same behavior.

I can't see any leaks on the vehicle. This behavior does not seem to be influenced by A/C, heater, or any other driving conditions. Oil is not milky (and coolant is not oily) so it does not appear to be a head gasket issue. Temperatures look fine, even when the coolant bottle is empty.

Where might my coolant be going? And why does it hold for so long and suddenly drop, as opposed to slowly decreasing over time as one would expect with a leak?

Answer (score 1):

The filler cap may need replacing.  They are designed to open at a specific pressure, but it may be releasing at a lower pressure and dumping some of the coolant.

I have seen this before where the coolant will be happy at a low level in the header tank and never get any lower, but filling up to the correct level then driving for a while and the coolant drops.  A new filler cap fixed it.

Comment: Interesting. What would be the best way to detect this? I assume it would be dumping coolant all over the radiator?

Comment: There will be an overflow pipe coming off the top of the  expansion tank.  The coolant will be coming out of there if my suggestion is correct.

Comment: thanks! I've never actually caught this happening "in the act", but I'm sure I can come up with a clever solution (bucket on the overflow hose or something) to catch this darn truck red handed

Comment: Sounds like a plan.